# How do I add a method so I can just a String instead of typing a whole statement

Tags: java, bluej

how do i make it so i only have to type "onion" instead of typing the whole thing.
I am trying add a String for the Flavour of PackOfCrisps, but i have to type:

new PackOfCrisps("onion")

this is what i have done for the method

```
public void addPack(PackOfCrisps pack) {
      if (packets.size() < capacity) {
         packets.add(pack);
         
      } 
      else {
         System.out.println("capacity reached");
      }
   }
```

[image]
and this is the interface i get where i have to type:
new PackOfCrisps("onion")

Comment: Create a new method where the argument type is `String`, not `PackOfCrisps`.

Comment: but in my specification it says i have to use the argument ```PackOfCrisps```

Comment: You can keep the other method as it is, you can create a *new* method with the argument types you want, in this case a `String`.

Comment: so the other method can have the same name like addPack? and i do it like: ``` public void addPack(String pack){  addPack(new (PackOfCrisps(pack));} ```

Comment: Something like that, yes, it's called "method overloading".

Comment: ohh ok i am new to java started 1 week ago so dont know much in depth thank you.

Comment: ohh and @Progman can i leave the addPack method with (PackOfCrisps pack) argument empty? because it has no use, also for the specification the specificly said that i have to use PackOfCrisps as the argument so i was a lil scared that it might not work.

Comment: You can't leave the `addPack(PackOfCrisps);` method empty, it is most likely supposed to add such a pack to your packets. If you leave the method empty, nothing happens. Besides, you will call this method from the other `addPack(String);` method anyway to add your `PackOfCrisps`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that takes a String as an input and creates a PackOfCrisps out of it. You can then have that method use your already existing method to insert this new PackOfCrisps object.

```java
public void addPackByFlavour(String flavour) {
    // create a new object with the given flavour
    PackOfCrisps pack = new PackOfCrisps(flavour);

    // insert that object by using the already existing method
    addPack(pack);
}
```